# how to handle home button press event in android?

Tags: android

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Home button pressed!");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I am new to Android Development, I know how to handle back button but I don't know how to handle home button.

Comment: We don't user capital letters in the middle of sentence unless its a proper noun or referring to God.

Answer (score 1):

After `Android 4.0 (ICS)` this `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME` constant has been deprecated for some security reasons. That constant was preventing users from exiting app, users were being forced to remain in app until a specific case is finished. That can be for any purpose but problem occurs when it is used as a spam or other security issues. You can detect home key press event but you can not prevent app from minimizing.

Comment: so how can i detect home button press event ??